# Azure Data Flows - dynamic Group By

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Flows, in an Aggregate Transform is it possible to dynamically include columns in the Group By? I have 8 columns that could be needed in the Group By depending on their value i.e. if the value is 1 include in the Group By.

Simplifying to 2 columns:

```
Column1     Column2
1           1

Group By Column1, Column2

Column1     Column2
1           0

Group By Column1
```

Comment: Is there one or several rows in data flow? If there is just one row then the result of group by Column1, Column2  is same as Group By Column1. And each column contains 0 or 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the expression builder link in the aggregate group by field to add dynamic content. You can use parameters, columns, and expressions there. You can also define custom columns using a Derived Column before your Aggregate and use those columns here in the group by.

[image]